# RavenDB : Difficulty with two WHERE Query

Tags: ravendb

I have a situation where I want to do a query by two fields, I thought this would be pretty simple, but it is proving a great deal more difficult than I thought.

This is a rough look at the document being queried...

```
class Item {
   string Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
   Origin Origin { get; set; }
}

class Origin {
   string Id { get; set; }
   string Name { get; set; }
}
```

There are other fields, of course. I am just listing the relevant ones. So my Index looks like this.

```
public class Item__ByName : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Models.Items.Item, Item__ByName.Result> {

    public class Result {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Origin { get; set; }
    }

    public Item__ByName() {
        Map = items => from item in items
                       select new Result {
                           Id = item.Id,
                           Name = item.Name,
                           Origin = item.Origin.Name
                       };

        Index(i => i.Name, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
        Index(i => i.Origin, FieldIndexing.Analyzed);
    }
}
```

And then I attempt to query it like this...

```
var results = RavenSession
    .Query<Models.Items.Item, Indexes.Item__ByName>()
    .Where(n => n.Name == name)
    .Where(n => n.Origin.Name == origin)
    .ToList();
```

but it keeps telling me that "Origin_Name" is not defined. I am really confused about why it is saying this, when I've very clearly defined it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Index entry names cannot be nested.  Even though the document has structure, the *index* is flat.  To compensate for this, Raven uses the convention of replacing periods with underscores.  So in your index definition, you have to name your field `Origin_Name` to match.

  ```
  Origin_Name = item.Origin.Name
  ```
- There's hardly ever a need to include the `Id` in the index map.  It is handled differently behind the scenes, so it's included by default.
- You don't need a `Result` class in this scenario, because you aren't storing these fields or using them in a map/reduce.
- If you plan on doing a partial match, or a search, then having the fields analyzed is fine.  If you are only doing a whole string match, then you shouldn't analyze the fields.
- You should combine your `Where` queries into a single clause:

  ```
  .Where(n => n.Name == name && n.Origin.Name == origin)
  ```

  Alternatively, you can use the [Intersection Queries](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.5/client-api/querying/intersection) feature:

  ```
  .Where(n => n.Name == name)
  .Intersect()
  .Where(n => n.Origin.Name == origin)
  ```
- This particular query is simple enough that if you wanted you could omit the static index and Raven would create one for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use .And() and .Or() between two where's especially when you use advance query with LuceneQuery Object